# Specific arrival times for agents

Tags: simulation, anylogic, simulate

I have am model which simulates a distribution network.
I have a population of agents (customers), develop from a database (address -> Gis Location and the order time)
Also I have a order agent, which has a parameter "customer"
I have a source in the customer agent to generate orders and the code at source exit: `agent.customer = this;`
In the source I've set Arrival deffined by: Arrival table in Database and refer to the customer -> order time. My problem is, that I currently generating in every source of this population every order. How can I set up the source/model, that I generate at a specifc customer only the orders from this one?

Comment: Update: At the moment I work with a true/false check an and check the adress of the order and the store and only use the "correct" order and delete the rest. But I thinks there is a more efficent way to solve this problem because later the order table will contain 10.000+ data  and I cant imagine that it is really good to generate 10.000 agents every day and delete 9.900 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, a **Source** object can only ingest the whole table and there is not function to filter records. One way to go about partitioning *Order* agents is by creating all of them in a single source somewhere in the model and then using **Exit** to send them to an **Enter** object within a specific *Customer* agent. To summarise:

1. There is a single **Source** that reads the 'Orders' table for all customers
2. Each record has a field with 'customer id' so when agent gets created it has a property of which customer it belongs to
3. **Source** object feeds all new *Order* agents into an **Exit** object
4. Each **Customer** agent has an id and an **Enter** object
5. **Source**'s **Exit** object contains code which finds *Customer* agent based on 'customer id' property and then calls `customer.enter.take(agent)` to send the *Order* agent into the right *Customer* agent

More information about here: [Enter](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/enter.html) and [Exit](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/exit.html).